# Tem como identificar se um comando PostgreSQL pode travar antes de ser executado?

Tags: postgresql

As vezes preciso inserir um campo ou um index ou fazer alguma modificação mais crítica e muitas vezes peço para que todos saiam da base antes de eu executar o comando.

Esse comando na minha máquina mesmo com a aplicação executa normalmente, mas quando executo no servidor o comando fica pendurado até que todos saiam, vi que depende das tabelas em uso.

Não dá pra saber quais usuários estão usando quais tabelas, até porque eu uso um único usuário pra conexão e a aplicação é muito dinâmica.

Eu sei que alguns comandos não terão jeito pois exige acesso exclusivo a tabela.

Tem como fazer uma verificação se uma determinada tabela esta em uso e o comando que estou prestes a executar pode ficar travado?

Por exemplo em uma tabela com um campo tipo Bytea eu tentei adicionar mais um campo com a tabela em uso, mesmo sendo um campo simples varchar podendo ser null ele não deixa, mesmo saindo da tela que usa a referida tabela e fechando a tabela o comando continua pendurado até que se saia da aplicação, ou seja, desconectando mesmo.

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_da_parada, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem

Comment: Vichi, rsrsr, é @Miguel, as vezes pensamos igual o usuário, "esse problema me parece simples de resolver é só fazer isso ou aquilo", quando na verdade estamos criando um monstro, na minha cabeça talvez algo como o "prepare" resolveria, mas vi que a coisa é mais feia do que parece.

Comment: Eu lancei a pergunta porque eu também uso o MySQL e nele consigo dar os comando tranquilamente que ele não trava, mas num fórum me explicaram que o MySQL trabalha de forma diferente do PostgreSQL, por isso não lancei a comparação aqui.

Comment: Basicamente não consegues prever o resultado de um programa sem o executar. Mas não sei se a solução para isto passa por aí, talvez indo por outro caminho consigas

Comment: teria que ver como esta fazendo isso. Aqui no meu, uso apenas um usuário também, e mesmo com clientes conectados, faço alterações na tabela, sem problemas

Comment: Eu consigo fazer alterações, o problema está sendo quando a tabela tem um campo bytea, aí ele não deixa fazer... eu presumo que ele deva ler tabelas com bytea de forma diferente por isso a restrição, por exemplo o firebird me parece que guarda campos Blob em arquivo separado então a leitura é diferente. O comando é simples: ALTER TABLE public.tabela
  ADD COLUMN logotipo character varying(200);

Comment: sim, campos blob e text, não ficam armazenados na tupla, são ponteiros que apontam para os dados... mas, nas minhas tabelas tenho campos bytea também, e as alterações faço normalmente... por isso achei estranho

Comment: Voce trabalha com Delphi, usa CacheUpdates = True ? Se sim pode ser isso, mas eu não tenho como trabalhar com CacheUpdate

Comment: não... tenho aplicação em C# (winforms), ASP.NET e ASP.NET Core

Comment: de qualquer forma, você poderia forçar o encerramento da sessão do usuário: `select pg_terminate_backend(PID) from pg_stat_activity where datname = 'banco'`

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Você pode usar a variável de ambiente [`statement_timeout`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/runtime-config-client.html), que limita o tempo de execução máximo das operações no banco de dados.

Isso garante que nenhum usuário vai ficar *pendurado* executando operações no banco de dados por tempo indeterminado ou incompatível com a dinâmica do seu modelo/sistema.

No exemplo a seguir, se o tempo de execução exceder `60 segundos`, a operação será cancelada:

```
SET statement_timeout = '60s';
```

Alternativamente, essa variável de ambiente pode ser configurada permanentemente na `ROLE` do usuário.

No exemplo a seguir, o usuário `fulano` vai ser limitado a executar apenas operações que não levem mais de `120 segundos` na *database* `dbfoobar`, veja só:

```
ALTER ROLE fulano IN DATABASE dbfoobar SET statement_timeout TO '120s';
```

**2)** Para se identificar quais são as operações que estão sendo executadas pelo banco de dados em um dado momento, você pode fazer uma consulta na `VIEW` de sistema [`pg_stat_activity`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/monitoring-stats.html).

A consulta a seguir exibe a listagem detalhada de todas as operações em execução no banco de dados, ordenada pelo tempo de execução:

```
SELECT
  pid AS identificador,
  usename AS nome_usuario,
  datname AS nome_database,
  client_addr AS ip_origem,
  now() - query_start AS tempo_em_execucao,
  query AS operacao,
  state AS estado
FROM
   pg_stat_activity
ORDER BY
  query_start;
```

**3)** Ao se identificar uma operação em execução por um longo período de tempo, você pode forçar seu cancelamento por meio da função [`pg_cancel_backend()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SIGNAL-TABLE), que recebe como argumento o `pid`, ou *identifcador único* da operação a ser cancelada:

```
SELECT pg_cancel_backend( pid );
```